# Java Bubble Sort for an array of Scores

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying Bubble sort for an array of Score from a text file which consist of a String name and integer value scores. I tried with the code below but got an error of incompatible type issue.

```
 public static void bubbleSort(Score[] scores)
{
    int n = scores.length;
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        Score score = scores[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < n -i -1; j++)
            if(scores[j].getScore() > scores[j + 1].getScore())
            {
                //swap scores[j+1] and scores[j]
                int temp = scores[j].getScore();
                scores[j] = scores[j + 1];
                scores[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your temp variable is an int, not a Scores object. The error message is correct, that `[scores[j + 1] = temp` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That looks like a bubble sort (as your intent is to move the higher element to the "top" of the array) but i'm afraid the swap operation is not correct, do note that you shall do `int temp = scores[j]`. You are almost there!